# How to capture screen window content of Metro/UWP app in Windows 8.1/Windows 10?

Tags: c++, winapi, uwp, screen-capture

I'm developing a software which capture hidden screen window content of Metro/UWP app in Windows 8.1/Windows 10. 
It look very much like below: 
[Target overlapped window to capture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EwDYa.png)

Currently, I used the code of  GetWindowDC(hwnd) as below. I can capture overlapped window in Win32 app.

```
DC hDC = GetWindowDC(hwnd);
BitBlt(BitmapDC, 0, 0, width, height, hDC, 0, 0, SRCCOPY /* |CAPTUREBLT */);
ReleaseDC(hDC, hDC);
```

But I cannot capture overlapped window on UWP application on Windows 10:
[Capture result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KY0Wp.png)

I already tried to solve this problem by using GDI/GDI+ and DirectX but unsuccessfully.
Could you please support me to solve this touch problem?

Best regards,
Le Le

Comment: I would guess you have to delve deep down into the Desktop Window Manager. And maybe User Account Control. Remember though, that it's not your PC, it's Microsoft's.

Comment: The term [*Overlapped Window*](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms632599.aspx#overlapped) has a specific meaning in the Windows API. You seem to be using it to mean something else. Could you clarify your question?

Comment: @Cheers: *"Remember though, that it's not your PC, it's Microsoft's."* - Don't turn a technical limitation into a political debate. Culling invisible areas is an optimization, that's probably implemented into every OS, that wasn't designed to run on a machine with infinite CPU/GPU processing power.

Comment: @Cheers, Thanks for your suggestion. I researched about Desktop Window Manager. But it's very difficult to get the solution for that. as my know, GUI of Metro/UWP application then use WinRT with XAML to build.  Win32 app using component of Win32 API. I  think maybe when use win32 API cannot get capture from hwnd of Metro/UWP applications. is it right?

Comment: Hi @llnspectable, 
Sorry about not clearly.  above overlapped window not in the Windows API. Overlapped window to mean  the window be  obscured by a other window.  As in picture: https://i.stack.imgur.com/EwDYa.png, Caculator be obscured  by Microsoft spy++. 
Brs,

Comment: To clear this up: WinRT isn't some magic new implementation. It's a resource management wrapper around the Windows API. Modern UI applications construct a visual tree whose elements are displayed using DirectX. XAML is *one* way to construct the visual tree. An application can do the same in code as well. On-topic: You may get those screen captures using the [DWM Thumbnail API](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa969541.aspx).

Comment: Hi @llnspectable, Currently I used DWM Thumbnail API to capture target window, it's OK. 
But DWM Thumbnail API only get live preview thumbnail. I  cannot save that thumbnail to image file. 
*I refer to:http://bartdesmet.net/blogs/bart/archive/2006/10/05/4495.aspx .

Can there get bitmap data of thumbnail?